# Extend forms without page reload, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb

I'm searching for a solution to extend my form without page reload.
First I tried to render a partial with coffee or javascript, but escape_javascript didnt work.

Here's the view

```
<%= form_for @recipe = current_user.recipes.build do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Recipe Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= button_to "Add Ingredient", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary", id: "add" %>  
  <p></p>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The form above should be extented with following partial by every click on the button

```
  <div id="recipe-ingredients">Quantity
    <%= f.fields_for :quantities, @recipe.quantities.build do |quantity| %>
      <%= render 'quantity_fields', f: quantity %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

_quantity_fields

```
<%= f.label :amount, "Amount:" %>
<%= f.text_field :amount %>
<%= f.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
```

This approach did not work (recipes.js.erb)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("p").append("<%= escape_javascript 
    render(:partial => 'quantities') %>");
  });
});
```

There's a workaround (see below) but I'm searching for a better solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#workout-week").append(<%= escape_javascript(
    Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root,'app/views',
    '_show_period.html.haml'))).render(Object.new, period: @period)) %>);
});
```

**A second approach** is to write following lines in Coffee or JavaScript:

```
<%= f.fields_for :quantities, @recipe.quantities.build do |quantity| %>
  <%= f.label :amount, "Amount:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why not use `$('#workout-week').get(...)` and fetch the content you want there?

Comment: You might be interested in `cocoon` gem, which is specifically written for that purpose: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Thanks tadman.I thought ajax is used to fetch content from the database. But in the context of creating quantities, probably it makes sense to investigate ajax

Comment: Thanks BroiSatse but actually there is no need to muddy the water with 3rd part components. This would simply shift the issue in a different layer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with cocoon

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |quantity| %>
      <%= render 'quantity_fields', :f => quantity %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add', f, :quantities %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie so take this with a grain of salt, but have you tried using `render :foo` instead of `redirect_to :foo` in the appropriate controller function?

---

Comment: nope because when recipes#new is rendered, the form should be extended (through rendering a partial which contains div tag #recipe-ingredients) by clicking the #add link ;-)